# how to move Camera smoothly in unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, gameobject, lerp

When I want to move Camera from origin position to destination position,it looks so stiff.So if it can set move speed accordding to offset,how to do ?

Comment: What have you tried? If you don't post any code we can't know what you're doing, and can't suggest any improvements.

Comment: Please describe what you've tried!

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice tutorial on this problem, it is normally described at the beginning [of all tutorials](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials) on the unity website. Inside the [Survival Shooter Tutorial](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/camera-setup?playlist=17144) there is a explanation how to make the movement of the camera to the destination position smooth while moving.

Here is the code for moving the camera. Create a script, add it to the camera and add the `GameObject` you want to move to, into the scripts placeholder. It will automatically save the Transform component like setup in the script. (In my case its the player of the survival shooter tutorial ):

```
public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    // The position that that camera will be following.
    public Transform target; 
    // The speed with which the camera will be following.           
    public float smoothing = 5f;        

    // The initial offset from the target.
    Vector3 offset;                     

    void Start ()
    {
        // Calculate the initial offset.
        offset = transform.position - target.position;
    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        // Create a postion the camera is aiming for based on 
        // the offset from the target.
        Vector3 targetCamPos = target.position + offset;

        // Smoothly interpolate between the camera's current 
        // position and it's target position.
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, 
                                           targetCamPos,   
                                           smoothing * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [iTween](http://itween.pixelplacement.com/documentation.php) plugins. And if you want your camera to move with your object ie to follow it smoothly. You can use [smoothFollow](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/CarSmoothFollow) script.

Comment: I would recommend this too, iTween have a great amount of options to smooth movility, from cuadratic and curve which would make the camera move fast at the beginning then slow down at the end, the programming could be confusing for people who have not used iTween but it really worth it, joi, Nick's Answer pretty much the answer for this, be sure to mark it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Vector3.MoveTowards?  You can specify the step size to use, which should be smooth enough.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html

Answer (score 1):

```
public Vector3 target;        //The player
public float smoothTime= 0.3f;  //Smooth Time
private Vector2 velocity;       //Velocity
Vector3 firstPosition;
Vector3 secondPosition;
Vector3 delta;
Vector3 ca;
tk2dCamera UICa;
bool click=false;
void Start(){
    ca=transform.position;
    UICa=GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("UI").GetComponent<tk2dCamera>();
}
void  FixedUpdate ()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){


        firstPosition=UICa.camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        ca=transform.position;

    }
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)){


        secondPosition=UICa.camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        delta=secondPosition-firstPosition;
        target=ca+delta;

    }
    //Set the position
    if(delta!=Vector3.zero){
        transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.SmoothDamp(transform.position.x, target.x, ref velocity.x, smoothTime),Mathf.SmoothDamp( transform.position.y, target.y, ref velocity.y, smoothTime),transform.position.z);
    }

}
```